# i cant solve camera motion

Tags: motion-capture

[image]

I can't solve camera motion after tracking my footage.
I don't know what happened, if I messed up with tracking.

I don't understand *some data failed to reconstruct* meaning.

Comment: It basically means the trackers aren’t staying on stationary points, or the camera set up is wrong. Blender basically ended up with inconsistent equations.

Comment: It also says "see console for details".   Use the menu: Window :: System Console, to display the console